# Batch scripting limit with split list of strings and surround with tag

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following code that gets a list of comma-separated strings, surrounds them with some tag and writes the output to a file.
Works well for short lists, but for long (200 strings) lists, I get half-items

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /p CS_VALUES=<%1
SET TEMP_FILE="D:\tmp.txt"

>%TEMP_FILE% ECHO:

FOR %%i in (%CS_VALUES%) do (
    SET query="<quer:string>%%i</quer:string>"
    >>%TEMP_FILE% ECHO !query:~1,-1!
)

ECHO %TEMP_FILE%
```

So for the input: `A00000, A00001, .... , A00200`
I will get something like:

```
<quer:string>A00000</quer:string>
<quer:string>A00001</quer:string>
<quer:string>A00002</quer:string>
....
<quer:string>A00</quer:string>
```

(stopped at some variable <200 in the middle of that item)

I assume its related to some limitation but can't figure out which and how do I extend it (or if its not possible to extend - would be nice knowing whats the limitation)

Comment: [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) limits a string to 1021 (!) characters, so that's why it becomes truncated; reading a text file by [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) would limit lines to ~ 8190 characters. If you have longer lines, don't use batch scripting...

Comment: 8k is great, how would I go about changing my code for this?

Comment: Simply replace `SET /p CS_VALUES=<%1` by this: `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~1") do set "CS_VALUES=%%A"`

Comment: thank you! this is awesome.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put each value on a separate line in a file?

Comment: I don't control the input or the output format, just the way there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`set /P` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) accepts a line of text with a length of up to 1021 characters/bytes, that is why your text becomes truncated.

To accept longer lines, namely such with about 8190 characters/bytes, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) instead. In your code, this means to replace:

```cmd
SET /p CS_VALUES=<%1
```

By:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~1") do set "CS_VALUES=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `For /F` option example for you.

```bat
@Echo Off
>"D:\tmp.txt" (For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%~1"
        ) Do Echo ^<quer:string^>%%~A^</quer:string^>)
```